# Call to lp from Python causes script to exit

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, raspberry-pi, raspbian

The following Python script is tasked with taking a photo and then printing it. However, each time after the script successfully calls lp, the script exits (cleanly, with no exception or explanation)

```
import time
import picamera
import subprocess

def main():
    with picamera.PiCamera() as cam:
        cam.start_preview(alpha=220)
        #cam.resolution = (2592, 1944)
        cam.capture('test.jpg')
    subprocess.check_call("lp -d HP-270 test.jpg")

while True:
    main()
    time.sleep(5.000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this: [Subprocess is not compatibile with RPIO](https://github.com/metachris/RPIO/issues/15)

Answer (score 0):

Try separating your call to lp and its arguments into a list of strings. This is how you pass your command and arguments to the shell, by default `subprocess.check_call` does not have the shell interpret the raw string you give to it.

`subprocess.check_call(["lp", "-d", "HP-270", "test.jpg"])`

> [`Subprocess library: Frequently Used Arguments`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)
>
> args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence
> of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally >
> preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required
> escaping > and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file
> names). If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see
> below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed
> without specifying any arguments.

Comment: This is interesting, since the call does actually succeed as it is - I will try it and let you know!

Comment: Well I tried that - and unfortunately the problem remained. What I ended up doing was just moving the print call to a separate script, since calling the other script allowed me to not have to worry about the first script terminating